# Weighted Lucas Kanade - Gaussian Function MATLAB

Tags: matlab, opticalflow

I implemented the Basic Lucas Kanade Optical Flow algorithm in Matlab.
I used the algorithm from Wikipedia.

Since I want to improve this Basic optical flow algorithm, I tried adding a weightening function which makes certain Pixels in the beighbourhood more important or less important (see also Wikipedia).

I basically calculated the following for every Pixel in the beighbourhood and the Center Pixel itself.

```
for: Center Pixel and every neighbourhood-pixel
sigma = 10;
weight(s) = (1/(2*pi*sigma^2)) * exp(-((first-x)^2+(second-y)^2)/(2*sigma^2))
```

x,y ist the Center Point pixel, it always stays the same.
first,second is the current neighbourhood-pixel
Since I am using a 5x5 neighbourhood, (first-x) or (second-y) will always be one of these: "0,1,-1,2,-2"

---

I then apply the weight-values in each part of the sum.

---

**Problem:** With Sigma = 10 I don't get a better result for the optical flow than without the weightening function.
With smaller Sigmas it's not better. **Afterall there is no difference between the Output vectors with or without the gaussian function**

**Is there a way to improve this Gaussian function to actually make the vectors more acurate than without weightening?**

Thank you sooo much.

Comment: A sigma of 10 is huge. With a 5x5 kernel, you're only sampling the very middle of the huge Gaussian, and will essentially have uniform weights in your square neighborhood. Read here: https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/695/ --- You want to pick a Gaussian sigma of 2, 3 or maybe 5, depending on the level of detail in the image that is relevant (for finer relevant detail, pick a smaller sigma), then adjust your neighborhood size to the sigma, for example `size = 2 * ceil(3*sigma) + 1`. Please read more on my blog about Gaussian filtering: https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/tag/gaussian/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you apply the values, but it usually should make a little difference.

For a better optical flow you could :

- presmooth the images with a gaussian
- use a spatiotemporal Lucas-Kanade method
- or use a more advanced algorithm